# Sorting two arrays so that the second array sorting is based on the first

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays. First array contains user ids and the second array contains the number of matched answers against an excising data set. The size of these arrays will always be the same and currently the matched array value indexes correspond to those of user ids.

```
useridArr = [1a,2a,3a,4a];
matched = [12,2,5,11];
```

So here user 1a has 12 matched answers, user 2a has 2 and so on. Now how can I sort the matched array in descending order and at the same time, sort the useridArr accordingly. Thanks

```
useridArr = [1a,4a,3a,2a];
matched = [12,11,5,2];
```

Comment: Your question is the first example of usage in the documentation of [`array_multisort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php). Have you read it?

Comment: @axiac I don't think multisort is relevant in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `array_multisort`.

```
array_multisort($matched, $userIdArr);
```

will sort both arrays as you require.

```
array_multisort($matched, SORT_DESC, $userIdArr);
```

will sort in descending order as required in your comment. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php gives a lot more information on the capabilities of this function.

Comment: I think this will sort both arrays, loosing the relationship they have.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. maintaining the relationship/shared order between two arrays is the most important part

Comment: @FabioMarzocca that's what he's asking: order the matched array and order the user id array accordingly.

Comment: @FabioMarzocca wrong. It sorts both arrays **keeping** the relationship. Read the documentation of [`array_multisort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php#refsect1-function.array-multisort-examples), example #1.

Comment: @jimiss This demo shows it working: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/58eb2abb722b13d18ed618e0753f4c5c138bbfa4 Do you need a different result?

Comment: @axiac Correct, sorry. My bad.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I want the matches array to be in descending order (I edited the question)

Comment: @SimonBrahan thanks for the answer, it works fine! just out of curiosity, How would this solution look like if we add another array? say names=[]

Comment: @jimiss It will work for as many arrays as you like. However, at that point I think you need to reconsider the structure of your data. In this case I would build a single user data structure from my input and use `usort` to order the data. Something like: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ba6291fb64183910443c17c82cb92fe96ca56a2f